# Can I skip version number of iPhone app in iTunes Connect and Xcode?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store-connect

I have an app whose version number is 1.0.0 and which is already available on the App Store.

Can I set the version number of the next version of the app to 3.0.0 or 4.0.0 instead of 2.0.0?
Will I get a problem if version numbers are not sequential?


Is there a official documentation about this or do you know apps which use non-sequential version numbers or apps whose initial version starts from a number greater than 1?

Comment: instead of putting a question just try it.

Comment: @suryasingh iTunes Connect accepts any numbers except the numbers which you already used in the past for the app. But this does not necessarily mean any numbers will cause any problem in the future. I think version numbers are supposed to follow some rules. So, I think it is possible that iTunes Connect allows any version numbers mistakenly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apple does not have any restrictions on this. The only rule is that the version and build numbers must be greater than the current version when submitting an update. You can increment it however you want.

From my own experience, I have launched apps with initial version numbers greater than 1, and I have also updated them while skipping version numbers.

More information on updating your app(s) can be found on [this Apple Developer page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ReplacingYourAppWithANewVersion.html).

Comment: Thank you. Useful answer. Does your app's version begin from 1.0.1 or 2.0.0? Did you skip major version (e.g., from 1.1.0 to 3.0.0) or minor version (e.g., from 1.0.0 to 1.2.0)?